TS2307: Cannot find module '@...' on compile to JavaScript
I'm working on a Vue project. VueJs 3 with TypeScript is used. The project will be packed with Electron as a Desktop application.
If I run vite, everything works perfect!
If I run npm run ts to convert the TypeScript files to JavaScript, I get this error:
src/main.ts:2:17 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './App.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import App from './App.vue'
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~

src/router/routes.ts:1:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@pages/CalendarPage/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import CalendarPage from '@pages/CalendarPage/index.vue'
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/router/routes.ts:2:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@pages/IngredientsPage/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import IngredientsPage from '@pages/IngredientsPage/index.vue'
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/router/routes.ts:3:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/pages/ReceiptsPage/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import ReceiptsPage from '@/pages/ReceiptsPage/index.vue'
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/router/routes.ts:4:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@pages/ShoppingListPage/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

4 import ShoppingListPage from '@pages/ShoppingListPage/index.vue'
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/router/routes.ts:5:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/pages/SportsPage/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

5 import SportsPage from '@/pages/SportsPage/index.vue'
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/router/routes.ts:6:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@pages/EditReceipt.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

6 import EditReceipt from '@pages/EditReceipt.vue'
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/router/routes.ts:7:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@pages/EditDayPage/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

7 import EditDay from '@pages/EditDayPage/index.vue'
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/router/routes.ts:8:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/pages/PreferencesPage/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

8 import PreferencesPage from '@/pages/PreferencesPage/index.vue'
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/router/routes.ts:9:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/pages/WeightPage/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.

9 import WeightPage from '@/pages/WeightPage/index.vue'
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 10 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     1  src/main.ts:2
     9  src/router/routes.ts:1

I've got the problem since I've used aliases. I can not estimate, where the problem is. The compiler has also a problem with the './App.vue' import in main.ts. What's the configuration error?
Source code
vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '@components': resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
      '@stores': resolve(__dirname, './src/data/stores'),
      '@pages': resolve(__dirname, './src/pages'),
      '@scripts': resolve(__dirname, './src/scripts'),
      '@models': resolve(__dirname, './src/data/models'),
      '@enums': resolve(__dirname, './src/data/enums'),
    }
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'build/vite',
    emptyOutDir: true
  },
  base: './'
})

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "build/electron",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@stores/*": ["src/data/stores/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "@scripts/*": ["src/scripts/*"],
      "@models/*": ["src/data/models/*"],
      "@enums/*": ["src/data/enums/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/*"],
  "references": [{
    "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
  }]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "mealpro",
  "displayName": "Mealpro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Tobias Zoghaib",
  "description": "Mealpro is an application to bett plan meals. It calculates nutrition needs based on body weight, calories based on activities and intake based on meals. Add ingredients, create receipts, plan the days and generate a day range based shopping list.",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "main": "build/electron/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "vite:dev": "vite",
    "vite:build": "vite build",
    "vite:preview": "vite preview",
    "ts": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc --ext .ts ./src",
    "electron:dev": "tsc && concurrently vite \" electron .\" \"tsc -w\"",
    "electron:build": "npm run vite:build && tsc && electron-builder",
    "electron:preview": "npm run vite:build && tsc && electron .",
    "forge:start": "electron-forge start",
    "forge:package": "electron-forge package",
    "forge:make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^7.4.47",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.11.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.50.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.1",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "typescript": "^5.5.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.29",
    "vue-router": "^4.4.0",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.5.3",
    "vuetify": "^3.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-fuses": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron/fuses": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.5",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "electron": "^31.1.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.13.3",
    "vite": "^5.3.1",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.26"
  }
}


You can't use "tsc" because .vue files aren't valid JS or TS. It's unclear why you need this but you can use vue-tsc

There are multiple TypeScript files in my project, e.g. routes.ts which makes most of the errors...

It doesn't matter in which files the errors occur. Notice that all of the errors are about .vue imports. The point is that you can't do this with "tsc" for the reason above

But if I don't use aliases, it worked perfectly fine! And I don't know why the error occurs with the usage of aliases also for relative paths :/

"it worked perfectly fine" - can you provide a way to reproduce this? If this is true, I'd expect that you used vue-tsc at some point and it worked for you, but then switched to tsc for some reason. Again, the problem is not in aliases but the fact that .vue is not valid JS/TS. TS compiler (tsc) cannot process it. Try to execute the contents of .vue in a browser and it will fail with syntax error, because that's what it is to regular JS parser

The problem was the include folder. It pointed to the whole src directory, instead of the src/electron folder, where the index.ts and preload.ts are. Thank for the hint!

I found a solution. The include path in the tsconfig.json has to be changed:
Problem:
{
  ...
  "include": ["src/*"],
  ...
}

Solution:
{
  ...
  "include": ["src/electron/*"],
  ...
}

